# How to convert variable into string in python

Tags: python, string, variables

I have a problem similar to this, however I do not know what the term is

```
cat = 5
dog = 3
fish = 7
animals= [cat, dog, fish]
for animal in animals:
    # by animal name, I mean the variable name that's being used
    print(animal_name + str(animal))
```

It should print out

```
cat5
dog3
fish7
```

So I am wondering if there is an actual method or function I could use to retrieve the variable name being used as a string.

Comment: Why not use a python dictionary?

Comment: is there a way to do this without dictionaries?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/544919/python-can-i-print-original-var-name

Comment: Why do you need to avoid the use of dictionaries?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are basically asking "How can my code discover the name of an object?"

```
def animal_name(animal):
    # here be dragons
    return some_string

cat = 5
print(animal_name(cat))  # prints "cat"
```

A [quote](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/how-can-my-code-discover-the-name-of-an-object.htm) from Fredrik Lundh (on comp.lang.python) is *particularly* appropriate here.

> The same way as you get the name of that cat you found on your porch:
> the cat (object) itself cannot tell you its name, and it doesn’t
> really care — so the only way to find out what it’s called is to ask
> all your neighbours (namespaces) if it’s their cat (object)…
>
> ….and don’t be surprised if you’ll find that it’s known by many names,
> or no name at all!

Just for fun I tried to implement `animal_name` using the `sys` and `gc` modules, and found that the neighbourhood was also calling the object you affectionately know as "cat", i.e. the literal integer 5, by several names:

```
>>> cat, dog, fish = 5, 3, 7
>>> animal_name(cat)
['n_sequence_fields', 'ST_GID', 'cat', 'SIGTRAP', 'n_fields', 'EIO']
>>> animal_name(dog)
['SIGQUIT', 'ST_NLINK', 'n_unnamed_fields', 'dog', '_abc_negative_cache_version', 'ESRCH']
>>> animal_name(fish)
['E2BIG', '__plen', 'fish', 'ST_ATIME', '__egginsert', '_abc_negative_cache_version', 'SIGBUS', 'S_IRWXO']
```

For unique enough objects, sometimes you *can* get a unique name:

```
>>> mantis_shrimp = 696969; animal_name(mantis_shrimp)
['mantis_shrimp']
```

So, in summary:

- **The short answer is:** You can't.
- **The long answer is:** Well, actually, you sometimes can - at least in the CPython implementation.  [To see how `animal_name` is implemented in my example, look here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8875313/674039).
- **The correct answer is:** Use a `dict`, as others have mentioned.  This is the best choice when you actually need to use the name <--> object association.

Comment: I think it would be possible using traceback which I read somewhere. I could purposely cause an error with the variable and have this error put in a string then use regex to retrive the variable.

Comment: An interesting idea!  I would be interested to hear if you have some success with this method.

Answer (score 5):

Use a dictionary rather than a bunch of variables.

```
animals = dict(cat=5, dog=3, fish=7)

for animal, count in animals.iteritems():
    print animal, count
```

Note that they may not (probably won't) come out in the same order you put them in. You can address this using `collections.ordereddict` or just by sorting the keys if you merely need them in a consistent order:

```
for animal in sorted(animals.keys()):
    print animal, animals[animal]
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, work with f-strings:

```
cat = 5

print(f"{cat=}")
```

Result:

`cat=5`

Answer (score 1):

```
myAnimals = {'cat':5,'dog':3,'fish':7}
animals = ['cat','dog','fish']
for animal in animals:
    if myAnimals.has_key(animal): print animal+myAnimals(animal)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of putting the variables into a list, I would put them into a dictionary.

```
d={}
d['cat']=5
d['dog']=3
d['fish']=7

for item in d.keys():
  print item+' '+d[item]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would change to using a dictionary variable that would let you easily map string names to values.

```
animalDict['cat'] = 5
animalDict['dog'] = 3
```

Then you can interate through the keys and print out what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing the variable name with the string of the animal name:

In here:

```
cat = 7
```

cat is the variable, 7 its value

In:

```
cat = 'cat'
```

cat is still the variable and 'cat' is the string with the animal name. You can put whatever string you like inside cat even `cat = 'dog'`.

Now back to your problem: you want to print out the name of an animal and a correposnding number.

To pair name and number the best choice is to use a [`dict`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict), a dictionary. the `{` and `}` are representing a dict *(just to be complete also a `set` in some cases)*:

```
d = {3: 'cat', 5: 'dog', 7: 'fish'}
```

`d` is your variable. `{3: 'cat', 5: 'dog', 7: 'fish'}` is your dictionary. `3, 5, 7` are the *keys* of such dictionary and `'cat', 'dog', 'fish'` are the corresponding values.
Now you nedd to iterate on this dictionary. That can be done calling `d.items()`:

```
d = {3: 'cat', 5: 'dog', 7: 'fish'}
for key,value in d.items():
    print(value, key)
```

I reversed the value, key order diring printing to print the name before the number.

Answer (score 0):

A different form of fadop3's answer

```
cat = 5
cat = '%s' % cat
```

This turns the `cat` variable into a string.

Answer (score 0):

It was too old question, but for verity we can use

```
[name for name, obj in globals().items() if eval(name) in animals]
```

- we get

```
['cat', 'dog', 'fish']
```

- data

```
cat = 5
dog = 3
fish = 7
animals= [cat, dog, fish]
```