# Input a class name and remove an object of that class from a list

Tags: python-3.x, list, class

I want to remove an object from a list using a the variable 'classname'

```
list = [A, A, B]                    #objects inside a list  
classname = input() .               #x = A
list.remove(classname)              #the problem is that classname is a string
                                    #and the list has no strings
```

Comment: whats are A, and B?

Comment: You can't.  [An object doesn't know what name(s) it is bound to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9121991/674039).

Comment: @eyllanesc they are objects

Answer (score -1):

Some objects are aware of their names.  If `A` and `B` are classes, functions, methods, descriptors, or generator instances, you can use [`definition.__name__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#definition.__name__) to determine their names.

```
class A:
    pass

class B:
    pass

l = [A, B, A, B]
remove = "A"
print([x for x in l if x.__name__ != remove])
# [<class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.B'>]
```