# How to write a function to return the variable name?

Tags: python

I want a function that can return the variable/object name as str like this :

```
def get_variable_name (input_variable):
    ## some codes

>>get_variable_name(a)
'a'

>>get_variable_name(mylist)
'mylist'
```

it looks like silly but i need the function to construct expression regarding to the variable for later on 'exec()'. Can someone help on how to write the 'get_variable_name' ?

Comment: It's *far* more work than you think to do so.

Comment: why are you doing this?  Im almost certain there is a much better way to do what you want (I mean beyond the very brief explanation you gave)

Comment: the fundamental problem is that multiple names can point to the same object.

Comment: Wait, you want to get some name of a function argument so that you can use it in *exec*?  Almost certainly you've taken two wrong turns, then.  This is probably an example of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), where instead of asking for help to achieve your goal, you ask for help in implementing your not-very-practical solution.

Comment: thank you all for the productive answer. I think I have the clue to solve the problem.

Comment: ... But if you have the name `a` in order to call `get_variable_name(a)`, then you know what it would return (if it could exist)... `'a'`!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've seen a few variants on this kind of question several times on SO now. The answer is *don't*.  **Learn to use a `dict` anytime you need association between names and objects.**  You will thank yourself for this later.

In answer to the question "How can my code discover the name of an object?", here's [a quote](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/how-can-my-code-discover-the-name-of-an-object.htm) from Fredrik Lundh (on comp.lang.python):

> The same way as you get the name of that cat you found on your porch:
>   the cat (object) itself cannot tell you its name, and it doesn’t
>   really care — so the only way to find out what it’s called is to ask
>   all your neighbours (namespaces) if it’s their cat (object)…
>
> ….and don’t be surprised if you’ll find that it’s known by many names,
>   or no name at all!

---

Note: It is *technically* possible to get a list of the names which are bound to an object, at least in CPython implementation.  If you're interested to see that demonstrated, see the usage of the [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) module shown in my answer here:

[Can an object inspect the name of the variable it's been assigned to?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8875313/674039)

This technique should only be used in some crazy debugging session, don't use anything like this in your design.

Comment: Note that even that link gives you a list of the name*s* (plural) of an object.  There isn't really such a thing as "*the* name" of an object.

Answer (score 5):

In general it is not possible.  When you pass something to a function, you are passing the object, not the name.  The same object can have many names or no names.  What is the function supposed to do if you call `get_variable_name(37)`?  You should think about why you want to do this, and try to find another way to accomplish your real task.

Edit: If you want `get_variable_name(37)` to return 37, then if you do `a=37` and then do `get_variable_name(a)`, that will also return 37.  Once inside the function, it has no way of knowing what the object's "name" was outside.

Comment: Im not sure anything is "impossible" but that said it would be very dificult and hackey and subject to breakage

Comment: i don't need the value, i just need the str that tell the variable name been input to the function.

Comment: i hoped Python provide the build-in '__objname__' for the object. I fail to find that.  I just want this feature to add some dynamic for my application. Namely, I will generate a 'str_statement' regarding the variable, and use 'exec(str_statement)' to do the job. I know it is a bad habit, but it is the intuitive and do job quickly. (I build the application for myself, no security issue)

Comment: You can dig the name in the parent frame, but that's quite wrong unless he needs it for debugging purposes...

Comment: don't use `exec` for that and don't go looking for code names.  learn to use `dict` in case you need some correspondence between names and objects, it will be MORE intuitive and get the job done quickly!

Answer (score 0):

```
def getvariablename(vara):
    for k in globals():
        if globals()[k] == vara:
                  return k
     return str(vara)
```

may work in some instance ...but very subject to breakage... and I would basically never use it in any kind of production code...

basically I cant think of any good reason to do this ... and about a million not to

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good start, depending on the Python version and runtime you might have to tweak a little. Put a break point and spend sometime to understand the structure of `inspect.currentframe()`

```
import inspect

def vprint(v):
    v_name = inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_code.co_names[3]
    print(f"{v_name} ==> {v}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = 15
    vprint(x)
```

will produce

```
x ==> 15
```

Answer (score -1):

if you just want to return the name of a variable selected based on user input... so they can keep track of their input, add a variable name in the code as they make selections in addition to the values generated from their selections.  for example:

```
temp = raw_input('Do you want a hot drink?  Type yes or no. ')
size = raw_input('Do you want a large drink? Type yes or no. ')
if temp and size == 'yes':
    drink = HL
    name = 'Large cafe au lait'
if temp and size != 'yes':
    drink = CS
    name = 'Small ice coffee'
print 'You ordered a ', name, '.'
```

MJ

Comment: Returning a variable name based on user input to provide interactive feedback.

Answer (score -1):

If your statement to be used in exec() is something like this

```
a = ["ddd","dfd","444"]
```

then do something like this

```
exec('b = a = ["ddd","dfd","444"]')
```

now you can use 'b' in your code to get a handle on 'a'.

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps you can use traceback.extract_stack() to get the call stack, then extract the variable name(s) from the entry?

```
def getVarName(a):
    stack = extract_stack()
    print(stack.pop(-2)[3])

bob = 5
getVarName(bob);
```

Output:

```
getVarName(bob)
```