# Pythonic way to set variable name as string

Tags: python

```
data1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
data2 = [7,8,9,10,11]  


x = data1
y = data2
```

What I required are the strings of above variable as follows:

```
xlabel = 'data1'
ylabel = 'data2'
```

Rather than writing manually, how can I call using x like below:

```
xlabel = str(x)
```

But above is wrong.
So, how to do?

```
xlabel =???
```

Is there a pythonic way of doing it?

Comment: You want to set `x` and `y` to the name of the variables `data1` and `data2` ?

Comment: to the name of variables, but as the strings

Comment: Why do you want to do this? It's probably possible but I doubt it's a good idea.

Comment: There's almost no reason to ever do this in the global space. If you  want that kind of functionality, use a dictionary to store your values.

Comment: what do you want to do with the string?

Comment: I suggest you read [this](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html). Names aren't properties of objects, they're just "tags" to use to refer to them.

Comment: If you have the variable `data1` in order to write `str(data1)`, then it is within your power to write `'data1'` instead .. :)

Comment: this is just to avoid manual works. i have to use the same name of variables as the strings for further processing

Comment: Put the lists into another list and operate on the list of lists instead.

Comment: Then you should either use a dictionary if you want to index with strings or use a list if you just want to store them in order.

Comment: @wim there is difference between str(data1) and 'data1' in my codes, because the former one refers to the string of lists.

Comment: @Marcin  this is the other direction (getting the string from the object, not making an object from the string)

Comment: @puti the Pythonic way is **not to do this**. If you need to access the lists using a string, put them in a dictionary `{'data1': [...], ...}`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe i do not need to acess the lists as string; i need to access list's name as string.

Comment: @puti and several people have told you several different ways that that isn't a sensible thing to be doing. `str(x)` gives you a string representing the object the name `x` refers to (`x.__str__()`). There is **almost certainly** a better way to get around whatever has made you think you need this - if you explain what you're actually trying to achieve we might be able to help you find it.

Comment: related:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/12189000/674039

Comment: @jonrsharpe plt.scatter(x,y) then plt.xlabel(xlabel)

Comment: @jonrsharpe since xlabel is 'data1'. I did not want to write it manually

Comment: So where does that name `data1` come from to begin with? Please edit the question with a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: first the text file is read and data1 and data2 are used as two lists

Comment: So is the name `data1` read in from the text file? Or is that just the first dataset from the file (in which case, why not have a list and use `'data{0}'.format(index)`)? Again, **edit the question**.

Comment: @Wim It's the same thing - the mistake is to treat variables and variable names as data, rather than using appropriate data structures.

Comment: I think the "pythonic" way of doing what the OP is asking is to use your editor or sed or similar tool to replace all of "x" with "data1". E.g. '/s/x/data1/g'. Ok, so not really pythonic, but the way a pythonista might save the trouble of manually changing x to data1.

Comment: Maybe a noob question but I have the doubt. Why is not a good idea? Apartly it would not be so useful, Is there a reason to say it would be catastrophic?

Answer (score 5):

To see why this makes no sense, consider the following snippet

```
def magic_name_getter(object):
    # here be dragons
    return the_name

data1 = [1,2,3,4]
magic_name_getter(data1)  # returns 'data1'

data1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
data2 = [1,2,3,4,5]
magic_name_getter(data2)  # returns 'data2' (..or 'data1'?)

magic_name_getter([7,8,9,10,11])  # returns ... ummm ... ???
```

**Objects in python can have many names, or no names at all.**

So what you want, whilst [not impossible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8875313/674039), is very difficult.  Since the variable names are important data for your use case, you should instead be using a dictionary of *keys* and *values* mapping the names to the lists so that you have easy access to the names (keys) aswell as the data (values).

Comment: NameError: global name 'the_name' is not defined

Comment: LOL.  Exactly!  Glad you finally get it!

Comment: ROFL. I think the OP tried to run it. Original Poster, I don't think "magic_name_getter" and "the_name" will actually work. It is a thought experiment, not an empirical one. Just pretend it is "magic" and that it would work if magic were possible.

Comment: @wim please see my edited question. i could not get what i expected.

Answer (score 3):

You should really consider organizing your data, e.g., in a dictionary:

```py
a = dict(
    data1 = [1,2,3,4,5],
    data2 = [6,7,8,9,10],
    )

x = a.keys()[0]
y = a.keys()[1]

print x, y
```

Output:

```
data1 data2
```

Usually you won't need to store the keys in separate variables like `x` and `y`, but work directly on `a.keys()` or `a.items()`.

Answer (score 1):

`collections.namedtuple` might help you out:

```
import collections
Parameters = collections.namedtuple('Parameters', 'dataname, data', verbose = False)
x = Parameters('data1', [1,2,3,4,5])
y = Parameters('data2', [7,8,9,10,11])

>>> x.dataname
'data1'
>>> x.data
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> y.dataname
'data2'
>>> y.data
[7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
```

You would use it for your plot like this:

```
plt.scatter(x.data, y.data)
plt.xlabel(x.dataname)
```