# populating an empty dictionary with other dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

i'd like to know how to populate an empty dictionary with other dictionaries in the manner below:

```
newdict = {}

dict1 = {"key1": "value1"}
dict2 = {"key2": "value2"}
dict3 = {"key3": "value3", "key4": "value4"}

dicts_to_use = [dict1, dict3]
```

so a list is used to specify which ones to include, and newdict in this case should be populated such that it would show:

```
{'dict1': {'key1': 'value1'}, 'dict3': {'key3': 'value3', 'key4': 'value4'}}
```

im running into trouble referring to the dictionaries in the list and crossing across string/dictionary types

Comment: It seems like `dicts_to_use` could just as easily be a dict -- i.e. `dicts_to_use = {'dict1': dict1, 'dict3': dict3}` -- And then you're done because that's what you're asking for ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this.  The reason you can't is because there's [no reliable way](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8875202/674039) to get the string `'dict1'` from the object `dict1`.

Now, I understand your variable names in the actual code are probably different than this simplified example, yet the same issue that will still trip you up: in general, **an object  can't tell you what names it is bound to**.  It might be bound to multiple names, or none at all.

You'll have to rethink your approach to variable names.

Answer (score -5):

Use `eval`. (Note that I changed dicts_to_use to include the names of the dicts, and not the dicts themselves...)

```
>>> newdict = {}
>>> 
>>> dict1 = {"key1": "value1"}
>>> dict2 = {"key2": "value2"}
>>> dict3 = {"key3": "value3", "key4": "value4"}
>>> 
>>> dicts_to_use = ["dict1", "dict3"]
>>> for d in dicts_to_use:
...     newdict[d] = eval(d)
... 
>>> newdict
{'dict1': {'key1': 'value1'}, 'dict3': {'key3': 'value3', 'key4': 'value4'}}
>>>
```

Comment: (Why the downvotes? I think this is the kind of thing OP was looking for.)

Comment: `eval` is highly unsafe and it also leads to bad code. When OP is looking for this, you should give them a proper alternative instead, rather than a gun they can shoot themselves in the foot with.

Comment: @AndrasDeak just the foot?